# Android Multilevel Expandableview like Google fit.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I want to design a listview like google fit shows your data. First thing that comes to mind is using expandableListview. But Google Fit even provides a nested expandablelistview and that too with smooth transition of expanding and collapsing.

Any pointers on how to start with this design? 
How should my layout look like? 
What should be done in order to provide a smooth expansion and collapse?

[image]

P.s. : I am interested in designing listview only and not stuff like progressbar.

Comment: did found any solution to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

1. U can have a look at  [this](http://techlovejump.com/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/) link for multilevel expandable listview.
2. Also for same purpose on github you can look at [this](https://gist.github.com/st-f/2b2a838d3f0258c5c33f) repository.

These two links clarifies the multilevel thing.

3. And For smooth transition see [this](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/)

A perfect blend of these three will provide you with your desired design. good luck